# Update WSUS from MS Security Bulletin DVD

Tags: wsus, update

**Scenario**

Windows Server 2003, WSUS 3.0 SP1, <strike>No</strike> Bandwidth Limited Internet Connection, Microsoft Security Bulletin DVD

**Questions**

- How do you setup WSUS to import updates from this DVD?
- Is this even possible?
- How do you setup a WSUS server when you cannot sync with MS Update?

If this can be done with SCCM 2007 then please advise.

If you need any further information, please do not hesitate to ask. I have a feeling that what I would like to do is impossible without an upstream server.

**Update**

There is an Internet connection that is bandwidth limited. I would like to setup the master WSUS without Internet connectivity.

Comment: If there's no internet connection, are the updates really nessesary?

Comment: Updated the question to reflect there is Internet, just bandwidth controlled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest against setting up a method of manually importing updates to your WSUS server.  In my experience (with pre 2.0 at least), there would almost always be complications and probability of getting your database corrupted (it might be better now with 3.0, but I highly doubt it).  There's a way to copy updates to a disconnected WSUS, but I believe you can ONLY import from exported data of [**another WSUS server**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720486%28WS.10%29.aspx)).

I think you should be asking the question of how much time you're going to spend in getting the actual updates (how would you filter which ones get installed, for which software?), and how practical this method of Windows updates is really going to be.

I suggest you talk it over with your fellow admin folks and come up with an strategy of getting the server updates to your WSUS as intended by Microsoft (make sure you allow ONLY what's needed before downloading updates)... if this is a 'bandwidth tightening' + security issue (depending on the kind of control you have over your bandwidth/access), you could just enable the ports and/or sites for WSUS, as documented here: [**http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693717.aspx**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693717.aspx)

...or you could play with the solution provided by this link: http://www.wsusoffline.net/ (WSUS Offline Update).  Looks like it was recently  updated, so might still be relevant.

Cheers!

Comment: Marking you as the correct answer as no other answers have been given after all this time and my searches have yielded that this cant be done. You only have to choices: From MS or from another WSUS server.